# connection to mongodb in golang

Tags: performance, beginner, go, mongodb

I am building an API server in golang with mongodb. My `main.go` file looks something like this:

```golang
func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()  

    question := r.PathPrefix("/question").Subrouter()
    question.HandleFunc("", handler.PostQuestion).Methods("POST")
    question.HandleFunc("/{id}", handler.UpdateQuestion).Methods("PUT")
    question.HandleFunc("/{id}", handler.DeleteQuestion).Methods("DELETE")
    question.HandleFunc("/{id}", handler.GetQuestion).Methods("GET")
    r.HandleFunc("/questions", handler.GetAllQuestions).Methods("GET")

    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("could not listen on port 8080 %v", err)
    }
}
```

Every handler has some logic which changes data in MongoDB. Regardless of what I am doing with the question collection, this is common in all the handlers.

```golang
client, _ := mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"))
ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
err := client.Connect(ctx)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

defer client.Disconnect(ctx)
collection := client.Database("myapp").Collection("questions")
```

These functions are in `handler/handler.go`.

As you can see, I am using the official Mongo driver. What is the best kind of refactor which can be done?

Comment: Is the title any better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say this is common in all handlers:

```
client, _ := mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"))
ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
err := client.Connect(ctx)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

defer client.Disconnect(ctx)
collection := client.Database("myapp").Collection("questions")
```

So this means you're connecting and disconnecting to MongoDB *for each request*. That's incredibly wasteful. The MongoDB client is safe for concurrent use, so you can reuse the connection. Because I see code like this:

```
question.HandleFunc("", handler.PostQuestion).Methods("POST")
```

I know your handler functions are methods, so why not add the client to your handler type:

```
type yourHandler struct {
    coll   *mongo.Collection
}
```

Then, in your handlers you can simply access:

```
func (h *yourHandler) PostQuestion(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if err := h.coll.InsertOne(r.Context(), ...); err != nil {
        // write error response
        return
    }
}
```

Now your main function will look a bit different, seeing as we're not disconnecting the mongo client in the handler anymore, and we're not using a context with an arbitrary timeout. I suggest something like this:

```
func main() {
    // create the base context, the context in which your application runs
    ctx, cfunc := context.WithCancel(ctx.Background())
    defer cfunc()
    client, err := mongo.NewClient(
        options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error creating mongo client: %+v", err)
    }
    defer client.Disconnect(ctx) // add disconnect call here
    if err := client.Connect(ctx); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to connect to MongoDB: %+v", err)
    }
    // set collection on handler
    handler.coll = client.Database("myapp").Collection("questions")
    // rest of the code here
}
```

So now, whenever the main function returns, the application context is cancelled (which is used to connect the client), and `client.Disconnect` is called. The handler has access to the collection you're using, removing a lot of duplicate code, and removing the overhead of constantly connecting and disconnecting to MongoDB.

Inside your handler, I'm not using `context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)`. Instead I'm using the request context, which means once the request context is cancelled, the query context is. You could still set a time-limit if you want:

```
func (h *yourHandler) PostQuestion(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // context expires if request context does, or times out in 3 seconds
    ctx, cfunc := context.WithTimeout(r.Context(), time.Second * 3)
    defer cfunc() // good form to add this
    if err := h.coll.InsertOne(ctx, ...); err != nil {
        // error response etc...
        return
    }
    // success response
}
```

Currently our handler requires the field `coll` to be of the type `*mongo.Collection`, which makes it harder to test your code. Instead, you might want to change that field to take an interface:

```
//go:generate go run github.com/golang/mock/mockgen -destination mocks/collection_interface_mock.go -package mocks your.module.io/path/to/handler/package Collection
type Collection interface{
    InsertOne(ctx context.Context, document interface{}, opts ...*options.InsertOneOptions) (*mongo.InsertOneResult, error)
    Name() string
    // all methods you need
}
```

In your unit tests, you can now inject a mock collection interface, that you can control, allowing you to simulate error returns, etc...

Instead of exposing the `coll` field on your handler, then, you'll also want to create a constructor function to inject the dependencies of what I have in the main function above (`handler.coll = ...`):

```
package service

type Collection interface{} // interface as above, with go generate comment

type handler struct {
    coll Collection
}

func NewHandler(c Collection) *handler {
    return &handler{
        coll: c,
    }
}
```

I'll leave you with this as a starting point. Just one thing I've not yet mentioned: you're using `log.Fatalf` when `http.ListenAndServe` returns an error. That's fine. Why are you using `panic(err)` when `client.Connect(ctx)` fails?

Panic is something you should avoid as much as possible. Especially here: it adds very little (to no) value: the only information a panic dump will yield is whereabouts in the mongo package something went awry. You don't control that package, so just `log.Fatalf("Mongo error: %+v", err)` is to be preferred.

---

#### More details

Seeing as your handler functions are actually functions in a package, rather than methods (which I initially thought they were):

I'd refactor the `handler` package to contain a constructor, and have the actual handler functions as methods on a type. Something like:

```
package handler

type Collection interface{
    InsertOne(ctx context.Context, document interface{}, opts ...*options.InsertOneOptions) (*mongo.InsertOneResult, error)
    Name() string
    // and so on
}

// main handler type
type Handler struct {
    coll Collection
}

// New returns the handler
func New(c Collection) *Handler {
    return &Handler{
        coll: c,
    }
}

func (h *Handler) PostQuestion(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if err := h.coll.InsertOne(r.Context(), ...); err != nil {
        log.Errorf("Insert question error: %+v", err)
        // write response
        return
    }
    // success response
}
```

From your `main` package, this will look like this:

```
func main() {
    ctx, cfunc := context.WithCancel(ctx.Background())
    defer cfunc()
    client, err := mongo.NewClient(
        options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error creating mongo client: %+v", err)
    }
    defer client.Disconnect(ctx) // add disconnect call here
    if err := client.Connect(ctx); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to connect to MongoDB: %+v", err)
    }
    // create handler with collection injected
    myHandler := handler.New(client.Database("myapp").Collection("questions"))

    // configure router to call methods on myHandler as handler functions
    // the handlers will now have access to the collection we've set up here
    r := mux.NewRouter()  

    question := r.PathPrefix("/question").Subrouter()
    question.HandleFunc("", myHandler.PostQuestion).Methods("POST")
    // and so on
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. I am relatively new to the golang (coming from the python) and your answer is very insightful. One question. When you did `handler.coll = ...` in main.go. Did you mean `yourHandler.coll`? Because I have a package of the same name.

Comment: And when I do `handler.MyHandler.coll = ...`, the linter complaints `type handler.MyHandler has no field or method collection`.

Comment: @SantoshKumar If `handler` is a package name, then your handler functions clearly are just functions, not receiver functions/methods. Declare a type in the handler package, have a `New` function in htere to which you pass the collection (constructor style injection), and then assign (e.g. `myHandler := handler.New(collection)`). Then replace handler functions with methods (`handler.PostQuestion` -> `myHandler.PostQuestion`)

Comment: Added a bit more details to the answer, showing what the type in the handler package would look like, and how to use it in your `main` func. Accessing a type `handler.MyHandler.coll` isn't correct (you access fields on an instance, not on a type name). the `coll` field is (rightfully) not exported, and cannot be set from the `main` package, so you'll need to pass that dependency via a constructor (like I did).

Comment: I am getting an error at Collection interface definition. On `bson.M` I'm getting `expected type, found '.'` Is this the same signature from [mongo docs](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo?tab=doc#Collection.InsertOne), because in Mongo docs, InsertOne returns two value?

Comment: @SantoshKumar Yes, the `Collection` interface has to contain the methods from the `mongo.Collection` type. I'll update the answer to reflect this. Keep in mind, this is code review, not a copy-paste ready refactor of your code, so there's likely to be other issues/omissions. It's a starting point. I've not tested a single line of this code